# Iterating through a dictionary (hash table) and packing into a struct

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, dictionary, struct, byte

I'm writing a program in Python 3, and one task I'd like to do is to take a dictionary and send it over a network (using UDP). But since I can't send a dictionary over UDP without first converting it into raw byte data, I've decided to use the `struct` library and pack the keys and values into a `bytearray`.

My desired struct format is this:

[image: struct format]

I decided to use the [`struct.pack_into()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html#struct.pack_into) function, since I want to iterate over each `(key, value)` in the dictionary and pack them.

Here's my code so far with an example dictionary:

```
import struct
my_dict = {2: 4, 3: 1}  # I have 4 entries in this example.

# The length of my_dict is 2; multiply by 2 to get the desired value of 4.
num_entries = 2 * len(my_dict.keys())

# I need to pack "num_entries" itself, then each (key, value) entry.
# I multiply this total by 2 at the end because I need each value to be
# 2 bytes.
# E.g. if num_entries is 2, then I need space to pack the "2", then
# key_one, value_one, key_two, value_two. That's 10 bytes total.
b = bytearray((1 + num_entries) * 2)

for i, (key, value) in enumerate(my_dict.items(), start=1):
     struct.pack_into('!2H', b, i, key, value)  # Use 'i' as the offset.
     print(b)

# Now prepend num_entries (2, in this case) to the top of the struct.
struct.pack_into('!H', b, 0, num_entries)

# Print the final struct.
print(b)
```

My desired final struct output is this:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x01')
```

But instead I get this:

```
struct at this point in the loop: bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x02\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
struct at this point in the loop: bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00')
bytearray(b'\x00\x02\x00\x03\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00')  # The final bytearray. key=2, value=4 is not present!
```

It seems that I'm not packing into the struct at the correct positions. I'd like to get each `key` and `value` from `my_dict` and pack them, then move to the next `key` and `value` and pack them in the next two bytes over (hence my use of `enumerate()` to keep an iterator), and so on. Refer to the picture above. But it appears that the bytes are instead getting overwritten.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found another solution. Rather than using `struct.pack_into()` and `enumerate()`, I just called the `extend()` method of `bytearray()`, like so:

```
import struct
my_dict = {2: 4, 3: 1}  # I have 2 entries (keys) in this example.
num_entries = len(my_dict.keys())
b = bytearray()

b.extend(struct.pack('!H', num_entries))  # Prepend the number of entries.

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    b.extend(struct.pack('!2H', key, value))

# Print the final bytearray.
print(b)
```

---

The above gives me the desired output:

```
bytearray(b'\x00\x02\x00\x02\x00\x04\x00\x03\x00\x01')
```